# How to get intellij to warn about possible NPE without using nullness annotations

Tags: java, intellij-idea, nullpointerexception

For example, It'd be nice if I could get a warning somewhere for this:

```
public boolean doit(final List<Long> list) {
    return list.isEmpty();
}

public void go() {
    doit(null);
}
```

But I don't see one.

It's statically provable that a NPE not only *could* occur, but in this case *will* occur.

Thanks